# Where does the teaching come from that a non-Jew studying for conversion must violate Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, gentiles

I've seen the answers [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13447/is-it-a-discouraged-or-an-unacceptable-practice-for-a-gentile-to-keep-the-sabbat/13448) that say a non-Jew may not keep Shabbat, although I would definitely take issue with the green check-marked answer there that uses Sefer Shofetim, Hilkhot Melakhim uMilchamoteihem 10:11-12 for this assertion--the cited text does not even imply such a thing, instead it discusses the idea that a בן-נח who wishes to perform a mitzva for the reward of doing so, should not be prevented.  In Pereq 9, Ramba"m writes that an *idolater* (עכו"ם) should be scourged if he attempts to keep Shabbat or studies Torah, or creates any religious practice, telling him he is liable for death for doing so -- but it doesn't say anything about requiring a גר תושב, nor anyone else, to deliberately *violate* Shabbat ח"ו.

From my understanding, Ramba"m is concerned that the aku"m should know that he is liable to punishment from Heaven if he keeps mitzvot, because by doing so he is indicating a desire to be attached to the covenant...his scourging is to prevent him from damaging himself, not to prevent him from improving himself, as Ramba"m expounds in pereq 9.  No such pronouncement is made against a ger toshab.

Where does the teaching come from that a non-Jew (a בן נח) should be compelled to violate Shabbat, even in a small way?  Certainly a non-Jew should not say the full berakha for qidush, but a non-Jew not keeping Shabbat completely as a Jew does, is a very different thing from requiring the non-Jew to actively violate Shabbat.

Edit:  To be very clear here, I see it as a grave error to assert that the non-idolator non-Jew should be compelled to violate Shabbat -- Ramba"m in Hilkhot Melakhim uMilchamoteihem and Resh Laqish in the gemara of Masekhet Sanhedrin 58b (erroneously referred to as מ"ש by me in comments below--I was trying to shorten stuff up and was thinking Shabbat instead of Sanhedrin) are almost certainly discussing idolaters who are known to not have Jewish ancestry. The notion of compelling someone who has gone off the derekh, or whose great-great-great grandparents did, to violate Shabbat, is horrifying.  It is the same greatest problem with the notion of the "shabbos goy"--you don't know who is and isn't halakhically Jewish.  Just because they don't know they're Jewish doesn't mean you know that they're not Jewish.  By promulgating the teaching that a person who is not known to be a Jew should violate Shabbat, you could very well be compelling an unwitting halakhically Jewish Jew to violate a precept of Torah observance mi-Sinai.  What possible benefit is there in doing so for anyone?

Comment: Seems pretty clear that the idea comes from the sources you disagree with. Maybe you're right and everyone else is wrong.

Comment: I agree with the sources, I disagree that the sources say what other people are saying they say.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Tomer and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: For a review of relevant sources see [Contemporary Halachic Problems vol 4 ch 7](https://www.sefaria.org/Contemporary_Halakhic_Problems%2C_Vol_IV%2C_Chapter_VII_Observance_of_Shabbat_by_a_Prospective_Proselyte_and_by_a_Ger_she_Mal_ve_Lo_Taval?lang=bi) and more briefly [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/may-a-gentile-and-one-in-process-of-conversion-keep-shabbos/)

Comment: "_Ramba"m writes that an idolater (עכו"ם) should be scourged if he attempts to keep Shabbat or studies Torah, or creates any religious practice_" (1) Actually, in the edition of the _Mishneh Torah_, linked to in the green check-marked answer you mention, [it says](https://mechon-mamre.org/i/e510.htm#11): "**גוי** שעסק בתורה, חייב מיתה; לא יעסוק אלא בשבע מצוות שלהן בלבד.  וכן **גוי** ששבת--אפילו ביום מימות החול--אם עשה אותו לעצמו כמו שבת, חייב מיתה; ואין צריך לומר אם עשה מועד לעצמו" (my emphasis).

Comment: (2) [Eliyahu Touger' translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188355/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-10.htm#v9) translates עכו"ם as "gentile", and the [translation used by Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.10.9?lang=bi&lang2=en) translates it as "non-Jew".

Comment: So, there is definitely an issue here, Tamir Evan... because I do not own a copy of the Mishne Torah that uses the word גוי - "a nation" there, instead it uses the initialism עכו"ם -- "an idolator".  If indeed there are renditions of the Mishne Torah that have גוי there instead, I cannot fathom why it would be translated as "a gentile" instead of "a nation"...the abuse of the word גוי to represent "non-Jew" is not valid in halakhic discourse.

R' Touger's translation of עכו"ם as "gentile" is fine, as far as far as it goes, but a translation cannot be the basis for making halakhic assertions.

Comment: re: mbloch -- I am a fan of R' Bleich's Contemporary Halakhic Problems series, but the cites source makes the same conflation of "idolater" with "non-Jew" that I see as problematic in this entire idea ... an idiolator should be _scourged_ but that is because he is an idolator.  Keeping Shabbat is not his crime, his crime is pretense...and in Perek 9 of the cited text the Ramba"m makes that very clear.   The second source you cite comes closest to supporting the position that the non-Jew is _prohibited_ from keeping Shabbat, in its second citation, to a work with which I am not familiar (cont)

Comment: (cont'd) a work cited "Piskeiy Teshuvos", which I assume is the text Eichlers offers in a 6-volume set, produced by a R' Simcha Rabinowitz.  I'm sure these shu"t are highly respected and revered in certain Litvish circles, but that does not support the notion that there is a universal psaq that says that a non-Jew is not permitted to keep Shabbat.  Bleich's Contemporary Halakhic Problems vol 4 that you cited, relies entirely on מ"ש (58b) where it explicitly makes this assertion with respect to עכו"ם, as w/ every printing of Ramba"m's מ"ת I have.  Nothing about "non-Jew", only about "idolator".

Comment: Also, mbloch, belatedly, thank you for the warm greeting above.  My apologies for not acknowledging it sooner.

Comment: "the abuse of the word גוי to represent "non-Jew" is not valid in halakhic discourse." This isn't true. Can you validate this claim? I think everyone here knows it means non-Jew. The Talmud and Rambam say גוי everywhere but were censored to say עכו"ם

Comment: "The notion of compelling someone who has gone off the derekh" no one says a non religious Jew should violate Shabbos.

Comment: @תומרשילוח So ask "why does everyone understand the sources this way" or "what's wrong with my understanding of these sources" not the trivial question in the title currently. You know where it comes from. It comes from the common understanding of these sources, which you'd like to understand better.

Comment: @תומרשילוח if you want to ping someone with your comment, you need to put an @ sign before their name. Then they get a special ping to come see what you wrote

Comment: Similar question: "[Sources forbidding a gentile from keeping the Sabbath](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89269/1368)".

Answer (score 8):

The *gemarra* you cite in the comments ([Sanhedrin 58b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.58b.25)) is the source that a non-Jew is forbidden from observing Shabbos:

> ואר"ל עובד כוכבים ששבת חייב מיתה שנא' (בראשית ח, כב) ויום ולילה לא ישבותו ואמר מר אזהרה שלהן זו היא מיתתן אמר רבינא אפי' שני בשבת

Even though you are correct it says עובד כוכבים, an idol worshipper, it is well known that the Talmud when it refers to עכו"ם it often means any non-Jew, regardless of faith or practice. In truth, the Talmud originally said גוי, non-Jew, and was censored to say עכו"ם. This is corroborated by the [Friedberg Project for Talmud Bavli Variants](https://bavli.genizah.org/). All of their editions of the Talmud say גוי, except for the Vilna Shas (which you and I are using). This includes the [Venice edition of the Talmud](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%22%D7%A1_%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%94).

The same is true for the Rambam. Although the Vilna edition of the Rambam says עכו"ם, [all other editions](https://rambam.genizah.org) on the same website say גוי.

Now, this addresses the general question of a non-Jew not observing Shabbos. Normally, I would see no reason why this wouldn't include a גר תושב. However, there's a [Rashi to Yevamos 48b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.48b.6?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Yevamot.48b.6.1) which seems to say that a גר תושב is forbidden *in violating* Shabbos, obviously showing he could (and should) keep Shabbos. However, [Tosafos there](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.48b.6?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Yevamot.48b.6.1) and [in Kerisos](https://www.sefaria.org/Keritot.9a.13?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Keritot.9a.13.1) disagree, and assume it's equally forbidden for a גר תושב to keep Shabbos, as with any other non-Jew. I believe this latter approach is the predominent one.

You also seem to be wondering about a non-Jew studying for conversion. This is a matter of dispute. I believe most *halachic* authorities do not differentiate. However, some do. For example, Rav Asher Weiss, a contemporary and prominent Rabbi, [rules](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=22232&pagenum=83) that someone in the process of conversion need not violate Shabbos. This is based on [Tosafos Yeshanim to Yevamos 48b](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_Yeshanim_on_Yevamot.48b.2?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=bi), who write:

> וי"ל דזה כיון דדעתו להתגייר מצי לשבות

Comment: For anyone interested, the Venice edition of Masekhet Sanhedin [is available on HebrewBooks](https://hebrewbooks.org/20435). (It's version of the quote from 58b is [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20435&pgnum=117).) Also, HebrewBooks has older editions of the Mishneh Torah, that say גוי (like [this one](https://hebrewbooks.org/19401) on [this page](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19401&pgnum=682), and [that one](https://hebrewbooks.org/42253) on [that page](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42253&pgnum=739)).